# Change collapsing toolbar titlle into spinner

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How can I change collapsing toolbar title into an spinner? Like this [image]

Comment: Toolbar is just a ViewGroup, so you can add any layout you want inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Toolbar as ViewGroup

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandedImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/photo"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
             //Use a Relative layout or any viewgroup to arrange your spinner here
                   <Spinner 
                     android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Place your spinner inside your toolbar item and then use an adapter for your Spinner according to your need.

Comment: I can use it but this is not exactly what I want. If I use this code then whenever I scroll the layout spinner will get collapsed I want that spinner to be at the top when the view gets scrolled.

Comment: No, the spinner will not collapse, go it will stay visible inside the toolbar.